# Why does HTML select onchange="this.submit.form()" send no value?

Tags: php, html

```
<form method="POST" action="../inc/changeRole.php">
  <select class="form-control col-lg-12" id="profile_type" name="profile_type" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                  <?php

                  $tablejpt = $prefix . 'jt_profile_type';
                  $queryjpt = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM `$tablejpt` WHERE id_profile='$id_profile'");

                  while ($row = $queryjpt->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $id_lkp_profile_type = $row['id_lkp_profile_type'];
                    $tablelpt = $prefix . 'lkp_profile_type';
                    $querylpt = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT description FROM `$tablelpt` WHERE id='$id_lkp_profile_type'");
                    $datalpt = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querylpt);
                  ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $id_lkp_profile_type ?>" <?php if ($row['flag_active'] == '1') : ?> selected="selected" <?php endif ?>>
                          <?php echo $datalpt['description']; ?>
                      </option>
                  <?php } ?>
  </select>
</form>
```

This is from changeRole.php

```
<?php
include '../init/config.php';

// Update the database
if(isset($_POST['profile_type'])){
    // Get the selected value
    $selectedValue = $_POST['profile_type'];

    $tablejpt = $prefix . 'jt_profile_type';
    $query = "UPDATE `$tablejpt` SET flag_active='0', modify_by='$id_profile' WHERE id_profile='$id_profile' AND id_lkp_profile_type!='$selectedValue'";
    mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $query = "UPDATE `$tablejpt` SET flag_active='1', modify_by='$id_profile' WHERE id_profile='$id_profile' AND id_lkp_profile_type='$selectedValue'";
    mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../index.php">';
}else{
    echo "Error: Missing 'profile_type' parameter.";
}
?>
```

The issue here is that when I select any option, changeRole.php is called but the value from the selected option doesn't get submitted to $selectedValue in changeRole.php. Can anybody help me?

I have tried submit form using javascript but the problem is still there.

Comment: Do you get an error? What _is_ the value of `$selectedValue`? Did you `var_dump($selectedValue)` after you declare it? What does it output?

Comment: This is the error that I get, "Error: Missing 'profile_type' parameter."
The value of $selectedValue is nothing. I've tried echo-ed it and it shows nothing.
I didnt var_dump($selectedValue) after declare it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with the code you posted. `var_dump($_POST);` to see if any POST variables get sent. Does something in `config.php` maybe reset `$_POST`?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` return  `array(0) { }` . @brombeer

Comment: Check what `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` contains.

Comment: I think I remember having a similar bug many years ago, and it was caused by some messed up server-configuration. What kind of server are you running, and on what OS?

Comment: Do you get the same problem under PHP's built-in webserver? `php -S localhost:3000 -t /path/to/site/`, visit http://localhost:3000/ and see if the problem occurs there too.

Answer (score -2):

Your onchange event will submit the form as soon as the select element value changes, but it doesn't include the selected value in the form data that is submitted to the server.

You can remove the onchange event from the select element, and instead add a submit button to the form.

```
<form method="POST" action="../inc/changeRole.php">
  <select class="form-control col-lg-12" id="profile_type" name="profile_type">
    <!-- options here -->
  </select>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```